Is it possible to clear web browser "offline website data" programmatically (extension development)?
As known, "Offline Website Data" can be cleared as follows from the browser:

I tried to do that but there is no option to clear the "offline website data":
browser.browsingData.remove({ }, {
    "cookies": true,
    "history": true,
    "downloads": true,
    "cache": true,
    "formData": true,
}).then(() => {
    console.log("data have been cleared.")
});

Is it possible to clear the "Offline Website Data" through web extension development?
